# extremely fishy memory usage, unaccounted memory usage (10 gigabytes) ubuntu 20 focal overnight

Tags: memory-leak

extremely fishy memory usage, unaccounted memory usage (10 gigabytes) ubuntu 20 focal

ran overnight with bashtop monitoring and found that 10 gigabytes apart from ubuntus 3.5 gigabyte base usage had expanded overnight... ran

killall *
killall *.*
and the memory usage remained resident well after 15 minutes - at which point i rebooted and the memory cleared.

deep analysis with bashtop showed every running program was using less thana total of 3 gigabytes in use, but out of 16 gigabytes i had only 3 gigabytes left.

would really appreciate insight onto this memory leak or mystery program- cause when i ran ubuntu 8 and linux puppy three.. memory leaks were impossible.

so ive found out that as soon as you activate the software center application. that you recieve MALWARE. within 3 days

https://i.imgur.com/Xn2cknB.png this obviously modified imagemagic installed without my permission, doesnt list itself in the software center as installed or installable, DOESNT HAVE a directory, and shows no install log in su history. it also doesnt have any files in the default imagemagic installation folder, and the system doesnt find any results from clam av or trojanhunter. HELP! its also submitting and receiving 20 KILOBYTES of data when the system is idle from a fresh install. no steam or discord or any non system programs running, its contantly talking to a server but i cant identify the ip address as its not listed by tracing or active connection commands. theirs also no other visible partitions it created. this is serious garbage and needs a proper dumpster - and a genius++ to destroy it.

bump.

Comment: Run System Monitor.>>>Processes  you should be able to see what is eating the the memory. I had a problem with Firefox on my laptop, it was using GBs of memory.

Comment: When the problem occurs using your techniques, edit your question with the results of `free -h`, and a full screen display of `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.